# Properties of O notation in Stirling's approximation to the binomial coefficient

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Stirling's approximation can be written:
\begin{equation}
n! = n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n} (1 + O(1/n)) .
\end{equation}
Subbing in to the binomial coefficient we get:
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n} (1 + O(1/n))}{k^k e^{-k} \sqrt{2 \pi k} (1 + O(1/n)) (n-k)^{n-k} e^{-(n-k)} \sqrt{2 \pi (n-k)} (1 + O(1/n))} .
\end{equation}
However, I've seen the following in working in several places:
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}}{k^k e^{-k} \sqrt{2 \pi k}  (n-k)^{n-k} e^{-(n-k)} \sqrt{2 \pi (n-k)}} (1 + O(1/n)).
\end{equation}
**Question:** How do we get that $(1 + O(1/n))$ term out the back of the fraction?

**What have I tried:** I wondered if perhaps there was some result like:
\begin{equation}
f(n)(1 + O(1/n)) g(n)(1 + O(1/n)) = f(n) g(n) (1 + O(1/n)) ,
\end{equation}
or an equivalent rule for the ratio of two functions. However, it seems to me that a counter-example follows on setting $f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $g(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and we get:
\begin{equation}
f(n)(1 + O(1/n)) g(n)(1 + O(1/n)) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} O(1/n) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} O(1/n) + O(1/n^2) \\ = f(n) g(n)(1 + O(1/\sqrt{n})
\end{equation}
Is my counter-example wrong? Am I completely missing the point? Am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Can you see that it boils down to $$
\frac{1}{{(1 + O(1/n))(1 + O(1/n))}} = 1 + O(1/n) \,?
$$ Note also that $(1 + O(1/n))(1 + O(1/n)) = 1 + O(1/n) + O(1/n^2 ) = 1 + O(1/n)$.

Comment: Also in your "counter-example" it should be $$
f(n)(1 + O(1/n))g(n)(1 + O(1/n)) = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}O(1/n) + \frac{1}{n}O(1/n) + \frac{1}{n}O(1/n^2 ).
$$ You made mistakes in the algebra.

Comment: @Gary Yep you're right I totally ballsed up that counter-example. I think I see now. You're saying that $\frac{1+O(1/n)}{1} = \frac{1}{1+O(1/n)} = 1 + O(1/n)$? Is that right? Because if we write it out with limit notation the second fraction there is still converging on $1$ at a rate of $1/n$... Thanks very much for responding.

Comment: Yes, you basically use $\frac{1}{1+x}=1+O(x)$ ($x\to 0$) which is a weak version of the geometric series. Just put $x=O(1/n)$.

Comment: @Gary Awesome got it. If you want to paste your comments as an answer I'll happily upvote and accept.